# IllegalArgumentException when parsing JSON array with one item

Tags: json, parsing, grails, groovy

I really need some help with something in Grails.
I'm new to Grails, and making a backend for a gymnasium that handles routines, measurements, etc. 
The problem I have is when parsing a JSON to create a routine for a new or existing client. 
The routine is composed by a list of days, of a maximum of 4 days total.
To make long story short, when the JSON request is with only 1 day, I get the IllegalArgumentException and I'm running out of ideas regarding of why.
Please help me!
Here's a sample json:

```
{"objetivo":"test martes","fechaRealizacion":"2015-01-20T00:00:00Z","carne":115500153,"dias":[{"numDia":"1","ejercicios":[{"descripcionTrans":"1.1","idHoja":1},{"descripcionTrans":"1.2","idHoja":2},{"descripcionTrans":"1.3","idHoja":3}]}]}
```

And here's is the code where I parse the JSON request:

```
def guardar = {
    println request.JSON

    jsonObj = request.JSON

    Rutinas r = new Rutinas(jsonObj)
    def ide = request.JSON.carne?.toLong() ?:0
    r.perfilAsociado = requestService.getPerfil(ide)
    r.observaciones = r.perfilAsociado.observaciones

    println jsonObj

    ArrayList test = jsonObj.dias
    ArrayList<Dia> dias = new ArrayList<Dia>()
    def testO       
    for(int i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) {
        Dia d = test.get(i)

        ArrayList<Ejercicios> ejerAdd = new ArrayList<Ejercicios>()

        for(int j = 0; j < d.ejercicios.size(); j++) {
            testO = [idHoja: d.ejercicios.get(j).idHoja]
            Ejercicios e = Ejercicios.findByIdHoja(testO.idHoja)                
            ejerAdd.add(e)
        }
        d.ejercicios = ejerAdd
        dias.add(d)
    }

    r.dias = dias
    /**/
    try {
        insertRutinas(r)
        insertDia(r, jsonObj)
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        response.status = 500
        println ex
        render "Internal server error"
    }
    response.status = 201
    render r as JSON//requestService.encodeRutinas(r)
}
```

Edit:
The error is thrown when calling `ArrayList test = jsonObj.dias`
Here's the stacktrace:

```
| Error 2015-01-21 09:18:04,884 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [POST] /backend-gimnasio/rutinas/guardar/
argument type mismatch. Stacktrace follows:
Message: argument type mismatch
    Line | Method
->>   -2 | invoke0                         in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     57 | invoke                          in     ''
|     43 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
|    606 | invoke                          in java.lang.reflect.Method
|   1270 | jlrMethodInvoke . . . . . . . . in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor
|     90 | invoke                          in org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod
|    324 | doMethodInvoke . . . . . . . .  in groovy.lang.MetaMethod
|   2662 | setProperty                     in groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
|   1170 | setProperty . . . . . . . . . . in groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass
|   3702 | setProperty                     in groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
|   1741 | setProperties . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|   1718 | invokeConstructor               in     ''
|   1526 | invokeConstructor . . . . . . . in     ''
|    675 | invokeConstructor               in groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass
|    932 | invokeConstructorOf . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
|    362 | continueCastOnSAM               in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation
|    306 | continueCastOnNumber . . . . .  in     ''
|    262 | continueCastOnCollection        in     ''
|    214 | castToType . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    599 | castToType                      in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter
|    386 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . .  in gimnasio.backend.RutinasController$_closure2
|     -1 | doCall                          in     ''
|     -2 | invoke0 . . . . . . . . . . . . in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
|     57 | invoke                          in     ''
|     43 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
|    606 | invoke                          in java.lang.reflect.Method
|   1270 | jlrMethodInvoke . . . . . . . . in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor
|     90 | invoke                          in org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod
|    324 | doMethodInvoke . . . . . . . .  in groovy.lang.MetaMethod
|   1207 | invokeMethod                    in groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
|   1110 | invokeMethod . . . . . . . . .  in groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass
|   1016 | invokeMethod                    in groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl
|    423 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in groovy.lang.Closure
|     -1 | call                            in gimnasio.backend.RutinasController$_closure2
|    417 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in groovy.lang.Closure
|     -1 | call                            in gimnasio.backend.RutinasController$_closure2
|     -2 | invoke0 . . . . . . . . . . . . in sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
|     57 | invoke                          in     ''
|     43 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl
|    606 | invoke                          in java.lang.reflect.Method
|   1270 | jlrMethodInvoke . . . . . . . . in org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor
|    154 | invoke                          in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.MixedGrailsControllerHelper
|    375 | handleAction . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractGrailsControllerHelper
|    252 | executeAction                   in     ''
|    205 | handleURI . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    126 | handleURI                       in     ''
|     72 | handleRequest . . . . . . . . . in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleGrailsController
|     50 | handle                          in org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter
|    347 | doDispatch . . . . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsDispatcherServlet
|    870 | doService                       in org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
|    961 | processRequest . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
|    863 | doPost                          in     ''
|    646 | service . . . . . . . . . . . . in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
|    837 | service                         in org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet
|    727 | service . . . . . . . . . . . . in javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
|    303 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|     52 | doFilter                        in org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    198 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter                        in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|    344 | invokeDelegate . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
|    261 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    101 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    101 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    101 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter                in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    748 | invoke                          in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher
|    486 | processRequest . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    411 | doForward                       in     ''
|    338 | forward . . . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    178 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.UrlMappingUtils
|    144 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo in     ''
|    135 | forwardRequestForUrlMappingInfo in     ''
|    216 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter.UrlMappingsFilter
|    107 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    330 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    118 | invoke                          in org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor
|     84 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
|    342 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    113 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter
|    342 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    113 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter
|    342 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     -1 | call . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter
|    108 | processFilterChain              in com.odobo.grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestTokenValidationFilter
|     -1 | this$3$processFilterChain . . . in     ''
|     77 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    342 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     53 | doFilter                        in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter
|    342 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    146 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter
|    342 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    154 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
|    342 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     -1 | call                            in javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter
|    122 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in com.odobo.grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestAuthenticationFilter
|    342 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    199 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter
|     49 | doFilter                        in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter
|    342 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     82 | doFilter                        in grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter
|    342 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     -1 | call                            in javax.servlet.FilterChain$doFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in com.odobo.grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.RestLogoutFilter
|    342 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|     87 | doFilter . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
|    342 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain
|    192 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy
|    160 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    344 | invokeDelegate . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
|    261 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|     69 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter
|    107 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|     67 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . .  in org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter
|    107 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|     88 | doFilterInternal . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
|    107 | doFilter                        in org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter
|    344 | invokeDelegate . . . . . . . .  in org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
|    261 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    241 | internalDoFilter . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain
|    208 | doFilter                        in     ''
|    220 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
|    122 | invoke                          in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve
|    171 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve
|    103 | invoke                          in org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve
|    116 | invoke . . . . . . . . . . . .  in org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve
|    408 | service                         in org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter
|   1070 | process . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor
|    611 | process                         in org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler
|    316 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor
|   1145 | runWorker                       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|     61 | run                             in org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable
^    745 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: "I get the IllegalArgumentException" - where exactly is the exception thrown and can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Thanks for the response, please check the edit, I added the stacktrace and where the error is thrown

Comment: mismatch. Stacktrace  -1 | call                            in gimnasio.backend.RutinasController$_closure2  You will need to check this controller 2nd element within closure is a missmatch data type

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood what you said :(

Comment: can you tell us, which line in above example is 386?

Comment: Sure!
It is |    386 | doCall . . . . . . . . . . . .  in gimnasio.backend.RutinasController$_closure2

Comment: The thing I didn't understand was the closure thing, I really don't know what that means :/